# Is it possible to start activityB inside activityA? And how?

Tags: android, android-activity

**ActivityA** is main visible activity. I want to start **activityB** inside **activityA**. And build **activityB** in *FrameLayout* (or something like that) of **activityA**. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `ActivityGroup` and embedded it in there.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

```
public class ActivityA extends ActivityGroup {

    ...
    Intent b = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    Window bWindow = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(ActivityB.class.getName(),b);
    activityFrame.addView(bWindow.getDecorView());  // activityFrame being your FrameLayout
    ....
```