# Is is possible to open new intents in the same tab in android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-intent, screen, new-operator

I have a tab view and it works fine, but I would like to open new intents in a tab. At the moment when I open a new intent, it replaces the entire screen, tab included. What modifications are needed to make this open in the same tab?

Here's the code for opening a new intent:

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("my.massive.package",
                    "my.massive.package.SecondIntent");
            startActivity(i);
```

And here's the code for a new tab:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First")
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, FirstIntent.class)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with this: [Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Answer (score 1):

It must help you. You can use buttons as Tabs and Activities as contents:

[Is it possible to start activityB inside activityA? And how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076281/is-it-posible-to-start-activityb-inside-activitya-and-how)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all tabs and re insert them with the tab in question having different intent.
see http://www.coderanch.com/t/460859/Android/Mobile/TabHost-Remove-Tab

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the Android system. You can not exchange activities in a TabHost because the content of a Tab is not changeable.

One workaround would be that you exchange the content of your root layout of your activity shown in a Tab. I did this once and I can not recommend it because you will get a really complex activity.

Best solution: Redesign your app so that you do not need this functionality and more.